# Regular expression over alphabet A = {0 , 1, 2} for words that contain at least one 0 and don't contain 11

Tags: regular-expressions

I got that I can get (1) followed by not (1) like this 
$$ (0+2)^*1(0+2)^* $$
From this point I'm actually stuck. I can't set the (0) to be somewhere in expression. The only expressions I get are ambiguous (where I can get the same word different ways from regex) and quite long. Is there more elegant and right way to write this expression? Thanks!

Comment: Remark: Your regex does *not* cover all words not containing 11 because it does not include, for instance, 101 or 10101.

Comment: Also, for some languages, you might find it easier to build a finite automaton for it and then convert it to a regex (rather than trying to come up with a regex directly). I am not implying this is the case here, but it is probably worth a try.

Comment: The answer to [Regex for bit strings with at least two zeros but no consecutive zeros](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/100965/regex-for-bit-strings-with-at-least-two-zeros-but-no-consecutive-zeros) might be helpful.

Comment: You can get the $0$ in the expression by starting with it. The your expression will be $E0E$, where $E$ is the expression of all words that do not contain $11$.

Comment: @dkaeae Thank you for the remark! Completely missed this case! I will definitely try to build an automaton for this problem. Already searching for sources to understand the best methods to do so.

Comment: @HendrikJan Oh, I got this, thank you! So I just need to think of how \(E\) would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we know our word contains a $0$, so let's start with that:

$$0$$

Now let's assume that that $0$ is the first $0$ in the word. Then there may be arbitrary $1$s and $2$s before it, but $11$ is not allowed, thus $1$ must be followed by either a $2$ or by our zero:

$$(2 + 12)^*(10 + 0)$$

Now at the end we can have arbitrary characters, except for $11$. Thus each $1$ must be followed by a $0$ or $2$, or be at the end of the word:

$$(2 + 12)^*(10 + 0)(0 + 2 + 10 + 12)^*(1 + \lambda)$$

Here $\lambda$ is the empty string. If that isn't acceptable, we can distribute over the concatenation:

$$(2 + 12)^*(10 + 0)((0 + 2 + 10 + 12)^*1 + (0 + 2 + 10 + 12)^*)$$

Or alternatively we turn our logic around:

$$(2 + 12)^*(10 + 0)(1 + \lambda)(0 + 2 + 01 + 21)^*$$

And then distribute over the earlier concatenation:

$$(2 + 12)^*(101 + 01 + 10 + 0)(0 + 2 + 01 + 21)^*$$

These are all unambiguous, by the trick of recognizing a *first* zero, rather than the existence of an arbitrary one.

Comment: Thanks so much! I got the idea of setting 0 to be first and considering this determine every possible case before and after that 0.